# selecting MIN and MAX in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT MAX(arg1) as longest, MIN(arg1) as shortest FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
        WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
        AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-17' 
        AND event = 'CONNECT' 
        ORDER BY time DESC
```

but it is returning:

```
longest = 9
shortest = 10
```

what have i done wrong here? - they should be the other way around

Comment: Add some sample of your data that shows why 9 and 10 are wrong

Comment: Have you checked the type of the arg1-column? It should be numeric - not text.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like those fields are text, and you are finding the alphabetical max/min value.

"9" > "10"

Comment: i am unable to change the table structure, is there any way around this?

Comment: @user3223205 try `select(0 + arg1) ...`. That should cast arg1 into a number.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order by ASC?

```
SELECT MAX(arg1) as longest, MIN(arg1) as shortest FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
    WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
    AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-17' 
    AND event = 'CONNECT' 
    ORDER BY time ASC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause will not affect values returned by `MAX/MIN` function

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis:
They are stored as Strings, and "1..."<"9..."

Try:

```
  SELECT MAX(arg1 + 0) as longest,
         MIN(arg1 + 0) as shortest
    FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
   WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
     AND DATE(time) = '2014-03-17' 
     AND event = 'CONNECT' 
ORDER BY time DESC
```